# How to stop pycharm from overloading RAM?

Tags: python, pycharm

ive recently started with python using pycharm. My problem is, that whenever i start pycharm it first starts normally but after about a minute ,without touching anything, i experience sind lags, which ist caused by my memory running on 97% load. This ist due to many python processes opening in the background. These are all called "Python (32 Bit)" and usw about 0.9 MB a pice. In total ist about 3-4gb of memory occupied by these processes. Whenever i close pycharm these processes dont close, which leads to ne restarting my Computer.
I have 8gb of memory, but CPU and GPU are running compleatly normal.
Since i only managed to use pygame with pycharm, another IDE isnt an option.
Dies anyone knows how to stop that from happening or how i atleast can kill all the background processes?

Comment: You realize you don't *need an IDE at all* so of course simply *another* IDE is an option.

Comment: Anyway, the Intellij IDEs, although generally regarded as quite nice, are notorious for being memory hogs. But I don't think what you are describing is normal. I'm not sure how much help StackOverflow can be here. But maybe someone will recognize this.

Comment: So you have *thousands* of Python processes?

Comment: Yes i have thousands of Python processes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps, but you can change the amount of memory being used by PyCharm IDE using `Xmx` in `pycharm.vmoptions` ([JetBrains documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.2/increasing-memory-heap.html)). Note that you can simply kill the processes in the background manually in the task manager/terminal.

Comment: Unfortionatly that doesnt help. As I found out, Xmx was already set to 1015mb by default. I believe the problem is that the processes are executet via the normal python.exe. Therefor it is only executed by pycharm but not connected to it. Because of that i found out, that i can kill all of these processes by typing "taskkill /f /im python.exe" into cmd. If i do that while pycharm is running all of the processes reopen.